# How should I represent messages and message sending in Rails and ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I routinely want to send out messages to my application's users.

I was thinking of having a tableless model like so:

```
class Dispatcher
  def any_reason_to_send_message?
    if condition_met
      self.send
    end
  end

  def send
    # do the sending
  end
end
```

Should I write what I want to accomplish as instance methods (like above) or class methods? Or should I put this kind of logic in a completely different place (e.g. `module`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dispatcher is the thing that sends messages, not the message itself. No idea whether there is actually a dispatcher in your application. I would make a model Message. Message#send_message would be a completely sensible method. I would make Message a normal model saved in a table, because it is valuable to be able to look back and see what message was sent when and to whom.

Now, if you do have a bunch of code that sends messages -- a Dispatcher -- and are wondering where to put that, here's what I'd do:

- add a services subdirectory to app (next to models, views, etc.)
- add the directory to config.autoload_paths in config/application.rb

Now you have a place to put new kind of class: a service, which connects your app to something external. Your dispatcher.rb can go in there. I like to make services singletons so that they are easier to replace in tests. (Yes, I know singletons are evil in typed languages, but they're easy to get at in Ruby so it's less of an issue.)

You can have a Dispatcher#send_message(message) instance method, which sends the given message using whatever underlying technology is required, and a Message#send_message instance method, which just does `Dispatcher.instance.send_message self`.

Note that Ruby objects already have an instance method `send`, so I went with `send_message`.